# Query Laravel relations, products, storehouses and sales

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel to manage products and sales in different storehouses, there are four tables: products, storehouses, sales and saleItems witch look like this when simplified:

**Storhouse** id, adress, ...

**Product** id, name, ...

**Sale** id, store_id, ...

**SaleItems** id, product_id, sale_id, qty, ...

The question is how to get a list of the products and the count of sales for each of them in each storehouse, anyone has an idea how to do that?

Here are the models:

```
class Product extends Model 
{
    public function sales(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SaleItem');
    }
}

class Sale extends Model
{
  public function storehouse(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Storehouse');
  }
  public function items(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Saleitem');
  }
}

class SaleItem extends Model
{
  public function sale(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Sale');
  }
  public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
  }
}

class Storehouse extends Model
{
  public function sales() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Sale');
  }
}
```

Comment: list of products? does this list need to belong to a particular storehouse?

Comment: yes, a list of products with a count or sum of sales in each storehouse :/

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent is very useful for managing and querying basic relationships but it gets trickier to use for complex queries with various groups by, aggregators and such. I would recommend to perform an actual sql query in this case:

```
SELECT P.id, P.name, SH.id, sum(SI.qty) as quantity
FROM products as P 
JOIN sale_items as SI on SI.product_id = P.id
JOIN sale as S on SI.sale = S.id
JOIN store_houses as SH on store_houses.id = S.store_id
GROUP BY P.id, SH.id
```

You can use in laravel like this:

```
$result = DB::select('SELECT P.id, P.name, SH.id, sum(SI.qty) as quantity
FROM products as P 
JOIN sale_items as SI on SI.product_id = P.id
JOIN sale as S on SI.sale = S.id
JOIN store_houses as SH on store_houses.id = S.store_id
GROUP BY P.id, SH.id');
```

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try :)

Comment: I've posted below a modified version of your code, it works fine but still the output is not very usable, would you take a look.

Comment: I've upvoted your response, I figured out how to adapt it to my needs. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@gbalduzzi, thank you for the quick solution, you're wright, a classic sql query is the way to go, I've fixed some naming issue and it works now but the product infos are missing and I don't think the results are correct :/

```
$data = DB::select('SELECT P.id, P.name, SH.id, SH.name, sum(SI.qty) as sales
        FROM products as P 
        JOIN sale_items as SI on SI.product_id = P.id
        JOIN sales as S on SI.sale_id = S.id
        JOIN storehouses as SH on SH.id = S.storehouse_id
        GROUP BY P.id, SH.id');
```

and and other issue, the id here is that

```
    [
      {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Storehouse 01",
    "sales": "5.00"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Storehouse 02",
    "sales": "8.00"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Storehouse 01",
    "sales": "9.00"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Storehouse 02",
    "sales": "6.00"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Storehouse 01",
    "sales": "15.00"
  } ... ]
```

Comment: There are two columns named id and two columns named `name` in the result, so they get overwritten. Try `SELECT P.id as prod_id, P.name as prod_name, SH.id as storehouse_id, SH.name as storehouse_name , sum(SI.qty) as sales`